# Managed property after full crawl is still empty

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, managed-property, content-search-web-part, crawled-property

I have created a new managed property which maps to a crawled property in Search schema config.

I then carried out a full crawl and checked that the item in the list has been crawled which I can see.

Now in the Content Search Query WebPart, I then map the managed property to the field in the WebPart.  However it is empty. Is there something I am missing to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have mapped the correct crawl property of the list column, like **ows_InternalColumnName**.

Make sure the managed property is **Retrievable**.

Reindex the list and start a full crawl, then check if the results display.

1. In the List ribbon choose List Settings.
2. On the Settings page, under General Settings, choose Advanced settings.
3. Scroll down to Reindex Document Library or Reindex List, and click the button.

Comment: I think you are onto something. I think the crawled properties for Calendar events aren't correct for some reason. To test I tried using the ows_fAllDayEvent and it is mapping correctly. So there seems to be a problem with using the ows_Start_x0020_date property.

Comment: I mapped ows_EventDate & ows_q_DATE_EventDate and it now seems to work for the start date.  For the event end date I used ows_EndDate and ows_q_DATE_EndDate.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have mapped the correct crawl property of the list column, like ows_InternalColumnName and is retrievable.

Reset the index at Central admin level.
Navigate to Content Source -> Change URL to some dummy URL( This resets index in no time)

Once done, start a full crawl and check if the results display.